# Does going out of scope automatically deletes the dynamic array memory allocation?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *numbers, sum = 0, input, size = 0;
    const int CHUNK = 3;
    int capacity = CHUNK;

    numbers = new int[capacity];

    cout << "Enter the number(negative number to end): ";
    cin >> input;

    while(input >= 0)
    {
        if(size >= capacity)
        {
            capacity += CHUNK;
            int *temp = new int[capacity];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = numbers[i];
            }
            delete [] numbers;
            numbers = temp;

            cout << "Expanding by " << CHUNK << endl;

        }
        numbers[size] = input;
        size++;
        cin >> input;
    }

    cout << "\nYou entered: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    delete [] numbers;

    return 0;
}
```

Consider the code above, It's an example of resizable array. Where it keeps getting input from the user and keeps expanding the array accordingly by increments of 3.

Inside the "if" statement, I am dynamically allocating memory to the array "temp"

```
int *temp = new int[capacity];
```

I know that there must be a **delete** for temp to release the memory. However, I just can't figure out where to write it because if I do write it inside the scope of **if** statement then it ends up printing bunch of weird numbers. However, it works fine without it. Or does the memory automatically gets released when dynamic array goes out of scope?

Comment: If you can, don't use new and delete. Use `unique_ptr` as needed.

Comment: And no, a dynamic array managed by a raw pointer is never automatically released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete `temp` as you are assigning it to `numbers` which gets deleted later.

A simpler and safer way to manage pointers is to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` which free memory automatically when the variables go out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better way to make resizable array: use std::vector.
And your code is not exception-safe.
Using properly-developed components (for example, from the standard library) not only
speed-up the creation of code, makes it much shorter and simpler to understand its logic, but also makes it bug-free.